# Python - Script that appends rows; checks for duplicates before writing

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm writing a script that has a for loop to extract a list of variables from each 'data_i.csv' file in a folder, then appends that list as a new row in a single 'output.csv' file.

My objective is to define the headers of the file once and then append data to the 'output.csv' container-file so it will function as a backlog for a standard measurement. 
The first time I run the script it will add all the files in the folder. Next time I run it, I want it to only append files that have been added since. I thought one way of doing this would be to check for duplicates, but the codes I found for that so far only searched for consecutive duplicates.

Do you have suggestions?

Here's how I made it so far:

```
import csv, os

# Find csv files
for csvFilename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not csvFilename.endswith('.csv'):
            continue    

# Read in csv file and choose certain cells
    csvRows = [] 
    csvFileObj = open(csvFilename) 
    csvData = csv.reader(csvFileObj,delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace='True') 
    csvLines = list(csvData) 

    cellID = csvLines[4][3] 

# Read in several variables...

    csvRows = [cellID]

    csvFileObj.close() 

    resultFile = open("Output.csv", 'a') #open in 'append' modus
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile) 
    wr.writerows([csvRows])     
    csvFileObj.close()
    resultFile.close()
```

This is the final script after mgc's answer:

```
import csv, os

f = open('Output.csv', 'r+')
merged_files = csv.reader(f)
merged_files = list()
for csvFilename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not csvFilename.endswith('_spm.txt'):
        continue
    if csvFilename in merged_files:
        continue            

    csvRows = [] 
    csvFileObj = open(csvFilename) 
    csvData = csv.reader(csvFileObj,delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace='True')
    csvLines = list(csvData)
    waferID = csvLines[4][3] 
    temperature = csvLines[21][2]

    csvRows = [waferID,thickness]
    merged_files.append(csvRows)
    csvFileObj.close() 

wr = csv.writer(f)
wr.writerows(merged_files)
f.close()
```

Comment: When you will re-run the script (so, not the first time, but any other time), did data have been appended only in new csv files ? Or also in existing files ?

Comment: When I run the script two times in a row, it will append the same data to the output file again. .

Comment: You could somehow "mark and skip" files that you have already processed. One option is to rename the files with a particular extension, or prefix their names, so you won't search for them later. Better yet, save the list of files you have already processed either in an "ini" file or a simple sqlite database, and perform the lookup before you process any file, so you can skip what you've done already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the name of each file already handled. If this log file don't need to be human readable, you can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). At the start of your script, you can do :

```
import pickle

try:
    with open('merged_log', 'rb') as f:
        merged_files = pickle.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    merged_files = set()
```

Then you can add a condition to avoid files previously treated :

```
if filename in merged_files: continue
```

Then when you are processing a file you can do :

```
merged_files.add(filename)
```

And keep trace of your variable at the end of your script (so it will be used on a next use) :

```
with open('merged_log', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(merged_files, f)
```

(However there is other options to your problem, for example you can slightly change the name of your file once it has been processed, like changing the extension from `.csv` to `.csv_` or moving processed files in a subfolder, etc.)

Also, in the example in your question, i don't think that you need to open (and close) your output file on each iteration of your `for` loop. Open it once before your loop, write what you have to write, then close it when you have leaved the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I agree that opening and closing the output file can be kept out of the for loop.
I will look into the pickle module. What do you mean by "not human readable"? I would like to be able to read out and do manual data analysis on the output.csv in excel.

Comment: You're welcome. Did the rest of the answer helps you to reach your objective ?

Comment: I tried out the script and it works great: no duplicates are added during a second run of the same script.
I'm still stuck with two questions: 
1. I would like to add a list to "merged_files" but it seems to only take variables? 
'code'csvRows = [cellID,temperature]
merged_file.add(csvRows) 'code'
returns: TypeError: unhashable type 'list'
2. I would like to read the script in excel as a .csv so I can do data analysis. Can I 'unpickle' the file at the end of the script?

Comment: 1) In my example `merged_files` variable is a `set` so it can only accept hashable (i.e. non-mutable) objects. You can also define `merged_files` as a list (and so append mutable objects, like `list`s, to it) but the look-up will be really more costly as the list will grow up. 2) If you're log file need to be human-readable you can save it in non-binary mode (without pickle) as a .csv or .txt file (or as you suggest, even if stored with pickle, you can load it and saved it to a csv to make analysis on it). I will modify my answer.

Comment: Thank you mgc. I will add to my question the code that works for me in the end, following your comments.